# How to pass a value in common param in my sql statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an sql query on which I want to pass a param value and get the result but I am not able to achieve this.

```
SELECT  
CASE
    WHEN x>0 and x<=5 THEN  1
    WHEN x>5 and x<=10 THEN 2
    WHEN x>10 and x<=15 THEN 3
    WHEN x>15 and x<=35 THEN 4
    WHEN x>35 THEN 6
END
```

I want to pass value of x in above query and get the result.
Eg:
x = 7
result = 2

Comment: it is a way easier to wrap the query either in a function or store procedure? does that work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL you can use **SET** command: `SET @x = 7;`
Once you declared it you can use it in your query, something like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN @x>5 and @x<=10 THEN 2
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Use set @yourvarname=yourvarvalue then add @ to the parametrized variable, in your case @x

```
set @x=10;
SELECT  
CASE
    WHEN @x>0 and @x<=5 THEN  1
    WHEN @x>5 and @x<=10 THEN 2
    WHEN @x>10 and @x<=15 THEN 3
    WHEN @x>15 and @x<=35 THEN 4
    WHEN @x>35 THEN 6
END
```

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/344899)